# php/pear package for "remember me on this computer"

Tags: php, cookies, pear

I know this is usually done with cookies, but I am getting unpredictable results on different browsers and decided to look for a pear package that focuses on this.  Just wondering if there's a package (HTTP_Client for example?) that anyone has had success using for this particular situation.  Or actually, do people *never* or rarely have problems with the routine of setting a cookie manually and checking for them?  Is it common to use a package for dealing with cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such functionality in [PEAR::LiveUser](http://pear.php.net/package/LiveUser), though I strongly believe it will be overkill. Here's a description of the functionality you are requesting taken from the [end user docs](http://pear.php.net/package/LiveUser/docs/latest/LiveUser/LiveUser.html#methodsetRememberCookie):

> setRememberCookie   [line 1326] bool
>   setRememberCookie( string $handle,
>   string $passwd)
>
> If cookies are allowed, this method
>   checks if the user wanted a cookie to
>   be set so he doesn't have to enter
>   handle and password for his next
>   login. If true, it will set the
>   cookie.
>
> ```
> * Return: true if the cookie can be set, false otherwise
> * Access: public
> ```
>
> Parameters: string    $handle     —
>   handle of the user trying to
>   authenticate string       $passwd     —
>   password of the user trying to
>   authenticate

What about the cookie checking is giving you trouble? You could have the www vs. non-www, subdomain vs. domain, or any number of logic issues. I remember working on a PHP authentication system that did just what you are doing, but I also remember it being a bear to work on. Of course your mileage may vary. :)